# How to extract single particular tag value in xml using python and modify

Tags: python, xml

I want to read IntakeFanSpeedMax, IntakeFanSpeedMin tag value and update using python in below xml, tried many tutorials but not able to read and update it. Please help me on this, Thanks in advance.

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <RobotManager Checksum="CCA4FBB2C307EBE537BDCEAFB340F5F22ABE178951B0F7FDDFBDC8939D0A3CAC">
          <Setup>
            <AddressHostName>192.168.2.1</AddressHostName>
            <PowerStateMonitor>
              <PowerStateMonitor1>
                <CommPort>2</CommPort>
              </PowerStateMonitor1>
              <PowerStateMonitor2>
                <Pmu>
                  <!-- in seconds (minimum: 90; maximum: 150) -->
                  <AcNotPresentShutdownTime>120</AcNotPresentShutdownTime>
                  <!-- in degrees Celsius (minimum: 0; maximum: 100) -->
                  <BatteryTemperatureDifferential>6</BatteryTemperatureDifferential>
                  <!-- in RPMs (minimum: 3000; maximum: 5000) -->
                  <IntakeFanSpeedMax>4000</IntakeFanSpeedMax>
                  <!-- in RPMs (minimum: 750; maximum: 1300) -->
                  <IntakeFanSpeedMin>1000</IntakeFanSpeedMin>
</Pmu>
    </RobotManager>


my code:

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

fileXml = "C://Users//...//Documents//RobotManagerSettings.xml"
tree = ET.parse(fileXml)
root = tree.getroot()
IntakeFanSpeedMax = root.find('IntakeFanSpeedMax').text
print(IntakeFanSpeedMax)



getting below error:
"C:\Users\Sagar Hosamath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:/Users/Sagar Hosamath/PycharmProjects/Coord/venv/Scripts/xmlPath.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sagar Hosamath\PycharmProjects\Coord\venv\Scripts\xmlPath.py", line 6, in <module>
    IntakeFanSpeedMax = root.find('IntakeFanSpeedMax').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far, and in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: Share a VALID XML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking for nested tags, you need the following format

```
>>> root.findall(".//IntakeFanSpeedMax")
[<Element 'IntakeFanSpeedMax' at 0x000001E40DBE8D60>]
>>> root.findall(".//IntakeFanSpeedMax")[0].text
'4000'
```

It works if you have just one instance of this tag. If you have several, you'll need to find list of parent tags, and look inside them one by one.

**Update** per comment question: It seems like you have to assign a text, not integer, like below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
fileXml = "C://Users//..//Documents//RobotManagerSettings.xml"
tree = ET.parse(fileXml)
root = tree.getroot()
value = root.findall(".//IntakeFanSpeedMax")[0].text
if value == "4000":
    root.findall(".//IntakeFanSpeedMax")[0].text = "8000"
tree.write('output.xml',encoding='UTF-8',xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, how do I set and save the xml, I tried below code as suggested by you:

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

fileXml = "C://Users//..//Documents//RobotManagerSettings.xml"
tree = ET.parse(fileXml)
root = tree.getroot()
value = root.findall(".//IntakeFanSpeedMax")[0].text
if value == "4000":
    root.set(".//IntakeFanSpeedMax", 8000)
tree.write('output.xml',encoding='UTF-8',xml_declaration=True)

Comment: getting below error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be by using pyquery with the xml text, you can apply this as follows (this will also replace the tag values with the updated ones):

```
    from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

xml_text = '''        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <RobotManager Checksum="CCA4FBB2C307EBE537BDCEAFB340F5F22ABE178951B0F7FDDFBDC8939D0A3CAC">
        <Setup>
            <AddressHostName>192.168.2.1</AddressHostName>
            <PowerStateMonitor>
            <PowerStateMonitor1>
                <CommPort>2</CommPort>
            </PowerStateMonitor1>
            <PowerStateMonitor2>
                <Pmu>
                <!-- in seconds (minimum: 90; maximum: 150) -->
                <AcNotPresentShutdownTime>120</AcNotPresentShutdownTime>
                <!-- in degrees Celsius (minimum: 0; maximum: 100) -->
                <BatteryTemperatureDifferential>6</BatteryTemperatureDifferential>
                <!-- in RPMs (minimum: 3000; maximum: 5000) -->
                <IntakeFanSpeedMax>4000</IntakeFanSpeedMax>
                <!-- in RPMs (minimum: 750; maximum: 1300) -->
                <IntakeFanSpeedMin>1000</IntakeFanSpeedMin>
</Pmu>
    </RobotManager>'''

d = pq(xml_text)

max_obj = d('IntakeFanSpeedMax')
min_obj = d('IntakeFanSpeedMin')

print('Intake Speed Max: {}'.format(max_obj.text()))
print('Intake Speed Min: {}'.format(min_obj.text()))

new_max_value = '3000'
new_min_value = '300'

max_obj.replaceWith('<IntakeFanSpeedMax>{}</IntakeFanSpeedMax>'.format(new_max_value))
min_obj.replaceWith('<IntakeFanSpeedMin>{}</IntakeFanSpeedMin>'.format(new_min_value))

print(d)
```